# how do i can get whole data in a text file in C#

Tags: c#

i have performed some operation before i get the output .
my question is how i can write whole lines to a file or whole data  as i am getting output one by one .i want the whole output at one click
my code is given below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("F:\\assign.txt");
        // string newFile = "data.txt";

        // StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("F:\\assign.txt");
        // string[] files = File.ReadAllLines("F:\\assign.txt");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {

            // int i = 0;
            //for (i = 0, i++) {
            List<string> lineData = new List<string>();
            //string line = File.ReadAllLine();
            int index;

            string data;
            string db = "_";
            // string k = line;
            index = line.IndexOf(db);
            data = line.Substring(index + 1);
            //count operation//

            int count = 0;
            foreach (char c in line)
            {
                if (c == '_')


                    count++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < count - 6; i++)
            {
                index = data.IndexOf(db);
                data = data.Substring(index + 1);

            }
            lineData.Add(data);



            textBox3.Text = (data.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(data);


                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", 
    data.ToString());


        }
        // sr.Close();

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }
    } 
   // }
```

Comment: are you not already doing that `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", data.ToString());`

Comment: Won't these line of code overwrite the file on every iteration?

`File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt",    data.ToString());`  , maybe `File.AppendAllText` is more appropriate

Comment: I posted an answer below, but I think there are other issues with the body of your loop. What exactly are you trying to do with the lines? You are continually overwriting `data` in the inner `for` loop. Is that intentional?

Comment: no i am not overwriting data intentionally ,
i am trying to read all line perform specific function and write it in a file 
but it is not happening..please help me i want all lines after performing function to be written in a file

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are putting too many things inside your `foreach` loop, so you are both overwriting your `lineData` list on each iteration, and you're overwriting your file on each iteration.

Instead, declare your `lineData` before the loop, add lines to it inside the loop, and then write it to the file after the loop:

```
List<string> lineData = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // Loop body code omitted...   

    lineData.Add(data);                        
}

// Now use WriteAllLines to write your new lines to the file
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", lineData);
```

---

As a side note, the following code does the same thing as your original code, but is a bit more concise. The logic is to split the line on the underscore character (which creates an array of items), skip the first item if there are more than one, and then rejoin the last six items with the underscore character. I used a bunch of sample data to test, and the results came out the same as your original code:

```
List<string> lineData = new List<string>();

foreach (string fileLine in File.ReadAllLines("F:\\assign.txt"))
{
    var delimeter = "_";

    var lineParts = fileLine.Split(new[] {delimeter}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (lineParts.Length > 1) lineParts = lineParts.Skip(1).ToArray();
    var data = string.Join(delimeter, lineParts.Skip(lineParts.Length - 6));

    lineData.Add(data);
    textBox3.Text = data;
    MessageBox.Show(data);
}

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", lineData);
```